# Database or flat file for millions of records?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, sqlite, flat-file, database

Suppose that a tuple of four strings (date, name, type, price) is generated every 10 seconds. I'm writing a program in Python in order to store these tuples in disk for future use (only Read<sup>1</sup>). There are going to be  millions of tuples, so the "insert" operation is crucial here. What's the best solution to this problem? SQLite, Postgres, MongoDB, or flat file?

<sup>1</sup> I will read almost all the data in memory, from beginning to end. I don't need complex relational reads. For example, "SELECT price FROM table" is what I need. I won't use any indexes at all.

Comment: "only read" is a little vague... ***how*** is the data read? If you want random reads, flat files won't be fun. If you need complex relational reads, use a RDBMS. If not, mongo might be a better choice... What types of indexes would you need, etc. - this is a very broad question and far too little information. Also, at one insert every 10s, 100M would take over 31 years...

Comment: I will read almost all the data in memory, from beginning to end. I don't need complex relational reads. For example, "SELECT price FROM table" is what I need. I won't use any indexes at all.

Comment: Then ask yourself about non-functional requirements (replication, what happens in a crash, etc.). Flat files will do it and they're always fastest for bulk but I'd personally choose a mongodb. With WiredTiger, you also get compression which is probably helpful for this case... Anyway, I'd say this is a question of preference, any database could handle this, as can flat files...

Comment: Thanks for the correction. "Hundreds of millions" was way too much. Replication is not a priority. I've already coded a mongo-based solution and a sqlite-based solution. So the answer is "just pick one and go with it", right? I'll choose mongo then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely recommend mongo. With indexes you can have very good performance on that set of data.  With a flat file, you're going to have to manage all the complexities of a database system in your application logic (assuming you need this data with any form of urgency).  If you add an index on the field you're looking to query, you should be fine in the performance category, especially when you're only in the millions of records range.